# Model Data not binding to textboxfor after insertion in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm facing a problem in mvc 4, i have create action method where i insert the data in db and then return model to View but the model data not bind to hidden Field like Id and Voucher number,
in other fields data binds properly but the issue is with these Id and VoucherNum,  Id is primary key and VoucherNum is Unique.
I have mentioned the code and html.

**Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Payment payment)
    {
        payment.VoucherNum  = db.Payments.Count() + 1;
        Ledger ledger = new Ledger();
        ledger.CusId = payment.CustomerId;
        ledger.Date = payment.Date;
        ledger.Remarks = payment.Remarks;
        ledger.Type = payment.Type;
        string negativeAmount;
        negativeAmount = "-" + payment.Amount;
        ledger.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(negativeAmount);
        ledger.IsActive = true;
        payment.IsActive = true;

            db.Payments.Add(payment);
            db.Ledgers.Add(ledger);
            db.SaveChanges();

        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.Customers.ToList()
          .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, CustomerCode = x.Name + "-" + x.CustomerCode }
           ), "Id", "CustomerCode", payment.CustomerId);

        var model =  db.Payments.Find(payment.Id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

```html
<h2>Payments</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Vocher#</label>               
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VoucherNum, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly="true"})
                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Customer</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CusId, "--Select Customer--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>       
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Date</label>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "date"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Amount</label>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Type</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Remarks</label>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remarks, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "5" })
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Payment Receive" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
        </div>                  
    }
</div>
```

[image: Form View after insertion]

[image: inspected html of those textfields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the helper method will look in to the model state dictionary first to populate the value of the input. The model state dictionary currently has null value for the `VoucherNum`  before you saved it, and the helper method will use this value to generate the value of the input field.

To fix this, you can explicitly clear the model state dictionary before returning to the view,

```
db.Payments.Add(payment);
db.SaveChanges();

ModelState.Clear();

var p = db.Payments.Find(model.Id);
return View(p);
```

**Or** even better, follow the **PRG** pattern. With the **Post-Redirect-Get** pattern, After successfully updating the database, you will return a Redirect Response back to the client and the client will issue a totally new GET request to the server.

In your case, You can use `RedirectToAction` to return a 302 response.

```
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Edit",new {id=payment.Id});
```

This will tell the browser to issue a new GET request for `Edit` action method with the new id in the request url. Your GET action method will use this id and get the entity from db and return it.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model =  db.Payments.Find(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

I strongly recommend you using the PRG pattern.

Comment: i don't have any other action method @Shyju